# Custom Collection extends List<T> Add method

Tags: linq, collections, extends

I want to create a custom collection and add my own custom Add method. 
Scenario:

Teacher.Students.Add(Student s)

I want to put LINQ methods to save the teacher/student relationship to the database, not just add it to the list.

How can I do that? How can I know what "Teacher" object this is?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to set up and configure an ORM (Object-relational mapping), such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), that will manage this for you. In effect, you set up the data model, and the ORM framework will take care of persisting that information for you.